# I have changed the folder name containing my django project now I'm getting "OSError"

Tags: django

I have accidentally renamed my main folder containing django project and all the files now when I run the 'runserver' command I get the following traceback

OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: ''.

I even have changed the folder name back to original but I still am getting the same error.

Here is the link to complete error http://dpaste.com/2A30W6X

P.S. 'runserver' command was working fine before altering the name of the folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django have some restrictions to create projects in concern with the name, If i'm remembering right you can only use '_' as separator and any special caracter is allowed.

Comment: Actually I didn't change the name of any app but the folder containing my whole project.

Comment: Ohh ok, sorry, I've misunderstood the question. Django have some restrictions to create projects in concern with the name, If i'm remembering right you can only use '_' as separator and any special caracter is allowed.

Comment: Yes I have changed it back to the original name but it still is giving the error

Comment: @NoumanMalik, can you send the screenshot of the error stack trace please?

Comment: It seems to be failing importing bootstrap4 lib, maybe you can reinstall the virtualenv, don't know for sure why this happenend.